# How to make a checkbox and a graph size to fill a specific range using VBA Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

A few questions!

**Question One**

I'd like this program to create three checkboxes. I want one that says "days" to be in A2, one that says "hours" to be in A3, and one that says "minutes" to be in A4. Is there any way to make it resize to fill in that cell, or do I have to size it manually?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub CheckBoxMacro()
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(111.75, 28.5, 52.5, 17.25).Select
Selection.Characters.Text = "Hello World"
End Sub
```

I tried putting `Range("A2")` in where it has the numbers, but that didn't work.

**Question Two**

How do I delete a series from a graph? I'm making a graph using VBA, and it keeps adding a blank third series. It shows up in the legend, and I'm not sure how to make it go away.

**Question Three**

How do I make a graph fill a specific range? I found out how to do it using VBA a while ago, but I can't for the life of me find out how to do it again. I'd like a graph to fill a specific range, like F1 to K8. That way if the other columns to the left change due to user input, the graph while still stay in that range, making everything look nice.

Thank you!

Comment: **Question One** - What have you tried? We can help you better if you post where you have failed. **Question Two / Three** -> Peltier is a good friend for this: <http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/QuickChartVBA.html#deleteseries>

Comment: I'll add the checkbox code I have so far above, but it's seriously lacking.

Comment: that's good. we can then help you better

Comment: Follow the same logic that Peltier has in the link above for setting to a the location, height, width of checkboxes. Should be very simiar if not the same, if memory serves correct.

Comment: from the site @ScottHoltzman gives, this code allows you to arrange an object on a specific range: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/QuickChartVBA.html#coverrange

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a checkbox cover a cell

   ```
       Sub CheckBoxMacro  
         With ActiveSheet.Range("A2")  
           ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height).Select  
           Selection.Characters.Text = "Hello World"  
         End With  
       End Sub
   ```

   If the series is blank, perhaps you are not correctly identifying the source data range. Otherwise, try this to remove the last series from the active chart:

   ```
       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count).Delete
   ```

   This is similar to the answer to 1.

   ```
       Dim ChartRange As Range
       Set ChartRange = ActiveSheet.Range("F1:K8")
       With ActiveChart.Parent
         .Left = ChartRange.Left
         .Top = ChartRange.Top
         .Width = ChartRange.Width
         .Height = ChartRange.Height
       End With
   ```